# Example of a Hausdorff space that is not completely Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

A space is called  *completely Hausdorff*  if  for  any  two distinct  points  $x$ and $y$ there  are  disjoint  closed neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ . This is called  the  $T_{2{1\over 2}}$  axiom . So easily can be seen that  every regular space is completely Hausdorff. And a completely Hausdorff space is Hausdorff.

Now for the first case I  guess  $\mathbb R_k$  space will serve as a counter example. This is Hausdorff and if I have not made silly mistakes in deriving, completely Hausdorff as well  but  not *regular*.

I need to  find  an example of a space that is Hausdorff  but  not  completely  Hausdorff.

Comment: Engelking, General Topology,calls a $T(2\frac {1}{2})$ space an Urysohn space. In case you try to find this in,e.g, Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

The minimal Hausdorff topology from Steen and Seebach is an example.

Let $A$ be the linearly ordered set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,\omega,\ldots, -3,-2,-1\}$ in the order topology. $X = A \times \omega \cup \{a, -a\}$ where $a$ and $-a$ are new points with neighbourhood base $M^{+}_n(a) = \{a\} \cup \{(i,j) : i \lt \omega, j > n\}$ for $a$ and $M^{-}_n(-a) = \{-a\} \cup \{(i,j): i \gt \omega, j \gt n\}$ for $-a$. Then $X$ is Hausdorff and $a$ and $-a$ do not have disjoint closed neighbourhoods.